# Global connection Sql Query with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, node.js

I'm building a node.js application that connects to sql server for querying! The application is divided into Router-Controller-Model, and a file called *DatabaseConfig.js* that continues the configuration parameters of the database.

When I run the query in the model, the following error is called:

> `Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.
>       at Object.connect (/Users/myuser/Desktop/myapp/src/ServerJS/ServerJS/node_modules/mssql/lib/base.js:1591:31)*`

How can I solve this type of error?

**Model:**

```js
async function CaricaRisorseCantiere(IdCantiere) {

    var data=[];
    const query = "select  IdRisorseUmane,IdUtenteInserimento,u1.Nome+' '+u1.Cognome as InseritoDA,ExtraPreventivo,u2.Nome+' '+u2.Cognome as Risorsa,RisorseUmane.IdUtente,IdCantiere,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Data, 105) as Data,Descrizione,convert(varchar(5), OreInizio, 108) as OreInizio,convert(varchar(5), OreFine, 108) as OreFine,REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as Pausa,convert(varchar(5), Cast(convert(varchar(5), (OreFine - OreInizio), 108) as datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as datetime), 108)  as TotaleOre   from RisorseUmane  inner join Utente as u1  on u1.IdUtente = RisorseUmane.IdUtenteInserimento   inner  join Utente as u2 on u2.IdUtente = RisorseUmane.IdUtente where IdCantiere= @IdCantiere  order by convert(datetime, Data, 103) desc";
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(DbConfigJSON);

    pool.connect().then(() => {
        const request = new sql.Request(pool);
        request.input('IdCantiere', sql.Int, IdCantiere);

        request.query(query).then((result) => {

            for(var i=0; i<result.recordset.length; i++){     
                data.push({
                    IdRisorseUmane: result.recordset[i].IdRisorseUmane,
                    IdUtenteInserimento: result.recordset[i].IdUtenteInserimento,
                    InseritoDA: result.recordset[i].InseritoDA,
                    ExtraPreventivo: result.recordset[i].ExtraPreventivo,
                    Risorsa: result.recordset[i].Risorsa,
                    Data: result.recordset[i].Data,
                    Descrizione: result.recordset[i].Descrizione,
                    TotaleOre: result.recordset[i].TotaleOre
              });
            }
            return data;
        });
    }).catch(err =>{
         console.log("Errore: ",err);
    });

}
```

**DatabaseConfig.js**

```js
exports.config = {
    user: 'remote',
    password: 'xx',
    server: 'xx',
    database: 'xx',
    debug: false,
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        encrypt: false
    },
    pool: {
        max: 30,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }

};
```

Comment: Is is possible that you are running two queries at the same time?  I mean two function calls within a short time?

Comment: Yes it's possible But I do not know how to stop it! We could use pools

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest you try using the connection pool mechanism in mssql, this should allow you to keep multiple connections open.

Comment: @TerryLennox the fact is that I do not understand how to implement it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add a simple example of connection pool usage here:

```
const DbConfig = require('./DatabaseConfig.json');
const sql = require('mssql');

const query = 'select * from people';
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(DbConfig);

pool.connect().then(() => {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    request.query(query).then ((result) => {
        console.log('Query result: ', JSON.stringify(result));

    });
}).catch ((error) => {
   console.error('An error occurred connecting to the db: ', error);  
});
```

This assumes a table named 'people', you could rename as appropriate.

The DatabaseConfig.json file would look like:

```
{
   "user": "some_user",
   "password": "pw",
   "server": "db_Server",
   "database": "test_db",
   "port": 1433
}
```

Here's another example, returning the result from the function (as requested):

```
const DbConfig = require('./DatabaseConfig.json');
const sql = require('mssql');

const query = 'select * from people';
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(DbConfig);

async function testQuery() {
    await pool.connect();
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const result = await request.query(query);
    return result;
};

testQuery().then ((result) => {
    console.log('Result: ', JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it gives me this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of anasync function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3197) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Ok, there must have been an error connection to the db., let me update with a .catch block to show the error!

Comment: Make sure the config. you use in the DatabaseConfig file matches your db server, e.g. username, password etc.!

Comment: It was a wrong parameter in the json config file! But with this I have another problem (I updated the code above the current version) how do I wait until the for loop ends to make the data(array) return?

Comment: To get the data array to return you need to make use of the fact that promises chain. You'd do return pool.connect().then(...  and return request.then(.. this should result in CaricaRisorseCantiere returning a promise.

Comment: No problem, glad it helps!